# How to use React Form data to fill an object full filling TypeScript Interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a React form that will use the data I input to create an object. This object will fullfill a Typescript interface such that the only key value pairs that will be initialized will fullfill the interface schema. So far I keep getting errors saying

```
The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.
```

and

```
'QuizStructure' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

So I'm missing something that I haven't been able to find in the documentation and other posts. Any clarification is appreciated.

This is the code.

```
interface QuizStructure{
  name: string,
  age: number,
  hobbies: string,
  Backend: string,
  preferredLanguage: string,
  API: string,
  OAuth: string
}

type FormElem = React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;

function App(): JSX.Element {

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {

    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

    const obj: QuizStructure = {
      name: '',
      age: 0,
      hobbies: '',
      Backend: '',
      preferredLanguage: '',
      API: '',
      OAuth: ''
    };

    for(let [key,value] of formData.entries()){
      console.log(key,value)

      if(key instanceof QuizStructure){

      if(key==='age'){
        obj[key]= Number(value);
      }else obj[key]=value;
    }

    console.log(obj);

    }

  };
```

Comment: `instanceof` is javascript syntax not typescript and expects an object type (such as a `class`) and not a typescript type (such as `type` or `interface`). This means that when you compile your typescript to javascript the interface `QuizStructure` will not exist and you will essentially be left with `key instanceof `. Also something else seems to be going on with your logic if `key` matched the interface `QuizStructure` it would be some kind of object and not a string as the following if seems to suggest (`key==='age'`)

Comment: That makes sense why it won't work. My intention is to try and build up an object that needs to be checked at the end if it conforms to the QuizStructure interface. So far I'm running into a wall as to how to do that or if its even possible at all.